# SSL and authenticating users

Tags: java, security, rest, ssl

I have a REST API which clients connect over SSL (self signed cert 2048bit)

I was thinking of implementing the following security

1. The client requests a RSA public key from the server
2. Encrypts the username / password
3. Adds these to the header of EVERY REST call allowing the server to be stateless

The application involves users adding credit cards (the numbers themselves are encrypted) and purchasing products so security is critical

We also have very limited time from a iphone client point of view so I was hoping if the above would be suitable?

Comment: You said "I have a REST API which clients connect over SSL (self signed cert 2048bit)".  I hope that you intend to change that self-signed part if you truly care about security and intend to transmit credit card numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, when it comes to security, one doesn't want to reinvent the wheel. It's way better to use state-of-the-art technologies, so you'll benefits from others' (likely more skilled than you) work.

If you have a RESTful API on SSL, I don't think you have written your own custom TCP protocol. Likely you'll use HTTP, so since it's on SSL, you are on HTTPS.

When using HTTPS, your browser makes sure that the request is signed and encrypted so that only the other end (the service) can authenticate the client and decrypt the message. So there is no need to encrypt data and using custom headers. A simple cookie-based session is enough so you don't send users' passwords in every request.

Comment: Our clients will be iphone, android and we dont want any cookies or any session at all. We are hosting on AWS and want to add EC2 nodes on the fly. We are happy with adding credentials to every request. Just wanted to make sure we had no missed anything from a security point of view ...

Comment: @user1177292 So you plan to add a header like `X-Auth: asdf` to all of your requests. Maybe you don't know that a session cookie is simply a header like `Cookie: sid=asdf` sent along each and every HTTP request ;) A cookie is better because you **don't send your users passwords**, neither in plain text, nor encoded nor even encrypted, so no one will ever be able to reverse users passwords

Comment: The issues with using a cookie is that the client developers have to deal with it. The library they are using does not automatically handle cookies

Comment: A session ID can simply be sent along as en extra parameter, either with a POST, GET, PUT or whatever. It's the concept that matter: with a login and a session key, you don't send the password over and over again

Comment: Then the server needs to maintain a session mapping to the user. We want a stateless REST service

Comment: Stateless is an abstract concept. When it comes to a real app, one must engineer things and make compromises. A session in this case is simply for **security**, since a session is short lived and can easily be destroyed, while sending credentials over the wire for each request is certainly less secure. However, if you really don't feel like, there is still no need to encrypt anything on SSL. Facebook doesn't do it, Google doesn't do it, OAuth doesn't... The point in using HTTPS is integrity and confidentiality are guaranteed on the transport layer and you don't have to deal with them yourself.

Comment: I believe Raffaele is correct in that you do not have be concerned about the confidentiality of the header fields on the wire. They are protected by SSL while on the wire and that is quite good.